# Need help in following Python script

Tags: python, linux, image, curl, error-handling

I have to :

1. Iterate through each file in the folder
2. For each file:
      Rotate the image 90° clockwise,

   Resize the image from 192x192 to 128x128,

   Save the image to a new folder in .jpeg format

I've written following script:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
from PIL import Image

def load_images(folder):
    images = os.listdir(folder)
    dst = "/home/mayank/Music/"
    try:
        for img in images:
            with Image.open(img) as im:
                im = Image.open(folder + '/' + img)
                #Rotating Images 90 degree Clockwise
                new_im = im.rotate(-90)
                #Resizing all images from 192x192 to 128x128
                new_im = new_im.resize(128,128)
                #Saving all images in new file
                new_im.save(dst+"/"+new_im, format = "jpeg")
                im.close()

except IOError as e:
    print(e)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    dir = load_images("/home/mayank/Music/images/")
```

The path given is correct but whenever I execute this code, it shows the following message for some files between all the files:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ic_directions_transit_white_48dp'
```

You can download images by the following code:

```
curl -c ./cookie -s -L "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=$11hg55-dKdHN63yJP20dMLAgPJ5oiTOHF" > /dev/null | curl -Lb ./cookie "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&confirm=`awk '/download/ {print $NF}' ./cookie`&id=11hg55-dKdHN63yJP20dMLAgPJ5oiTOHF" -o images.zip && sudo rm -rf cookie
```

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

you must provide full file path on line

```
with Image.open(img) as im:
```

like

```
with Image.open(folder+img) as im:
```

also, for joining file paths, its better practice to use os.path.join() func (its os type independant), for example

```
im = Image.open(os.path.join(folder,img))
```

Comment: that seems like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49565298/pil-valueerror-unknown-resampling-filter-how-to-resize-images-uploaded-on-fla

resize expects tuple as size, so just do `new_im.resize((128,128))`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all your suggestions but I've encountered another situation after modifications suggested. This is my modified code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
from PIL import Image
import glob

def load_images(folder):
    images = os.listdir(folder)
    dst = "/home/mayank/Music/"
    try:
        for img in images:
            with Image.open(folder+img) as im:
                im = Image.open(os.path.join(folder+img))
                #Rotating Images 90 degree Clockwise
                new_im = im.rotate(-90)
                #Resizing all images from 192x192 to 128x128
                new_im = new_im.resize((128,128))
                #Saving all images in new file
                new_im.save(dst + new_im, format = "jpeg")
                im.close()

    except IOError as e:
        print(e)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    dir = load_images("/home/mayank/Music/images/")
```

Now I've encountered another situation, i.e.,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./images.py", line 26, in <module>
    dir = load_images("/home/mayank/Music/images/")
  File "./images.py", line 18, in load_images
    new_im.save(dst + new_im, format = "jpeg")
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "Image") to str
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is simple code to resize files of images in current folder:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os,glob
from PIL import Image

newsize=(128,128)

for file in glob.glob("ic_*):

    im=Image.open(file).convert('RGB') #to work with invdividual bands we have to convert it to RGB
    im.rotate(270).resize(newsize).save("/opt/icons/"+file,"JPEG") #you can replace /opt/icons with dir in which you want to store new format images
```

Answer (score 0):

this cod works fine if you use .jpg files:

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
from PIL import Image

def load_images(folder):
    images = os.listdir(folder)
    p = Path(folder)
    for images in p.glob('*.jpg'):
        Im = Image.open(images)
        name= str(images.parent)+'/images/' +str(images.stem)+'.jpg'
        resizedIm = Im.resize((128,128))
        resizedIm.rotate(270).save(name)
load_images('/home/mayank/Music/')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import glob
from PIL import Image

resized_pictures=(128,128)

for file in glob.glob("ic_*"):

  im=Image.open(file).convert('RGB')

  im.rotate(-90).resize(resized_pictures).save("/opt/icons/"+file,"JPEG")
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
from PIL import Image

source_dir = '/home/.../images'
destination_dir = '/opt/icons'

if not os.path.exists(destination_dir):
    os.makedirs(destination_dir)

for filename in os.listdir(source_dir):
    if filename.endswith('48dp'):
        input_image_path = os.path.join(source_dir, filename)
        print(f"Verarbeite Datei: {filename}, Pfad: {input_image_path}")

        input_image = Image.open(input_image_path)

        rotated_image = input_image.rotate(-90, expand=True)

        desired_resolution = (128, 128)
        resized_image = rotated_image.resize(desired_resolution, Image.LANCZOS)

        resized_image_rgb = resized_image.convert('RGB')  # Konvertieren zum RGB-Modus

        output_image_path = os.path.join(destination_dir, os.path.splitext(filename)[0] + '.jpeg')
        print(f"Ausgabebildpfad: {output_image_path}")

        resized_image_rgb.save(output_image_path, 'JPEG')
        print(f"Verarbeitung abgeschlossen: {output_image_path}")

print("Image processing complete.")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

pls try this,

```
    with Image.open(folder +  img) as im:

               #im = Image.open(folder + '/' + img)
```

rest of the code no change

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Can you please help me with the latest problem

Comment: so  output will be saved same input image file name

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. It really helped me